# В v-model вывести значения элемента из массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
        inputs: [{
            type: 'text',
            v-model: 'name',
            }, 
           {
            type: 'text',
            v-model: 'age'
            }, 
           {
            type: 'text',
            v-model: 'gender',
          }],
```

Как перебрать массив, чтоб записать в v-model название из элемента массива
На выходе хочу получить такую запись

```
<input v-model:="name" type="text">
<input v-model:="age" type="text">
<input v-model:="gender" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Когда создается экземпляр Vue, он добавляет все свойства, найденные в его `data` объекте, в систему реактивности `Vue` . Когда значения этих свойств изменятся, представление будет «реагировать», обновляясь, чтобы соответствовать новым значениям.

> Следует отметить, что свойства в `data` являются реактивными, только если они существовали при создании экземпляра (здесь имеется ввиду непосредственно дочерние свойства объекта `data`). Это означает, что если вы добавите новое свойство, то изменения этого свойства не будут запускать какие-либо обновления просмотра. Если вы знаете, что вам понадобится свойство позже, установить какое-либо начальное значение этому свойству

Информация из официального руководства - [Экземпляр Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)

Учитывая вышеизложенное, создаете пустое свойство в `data`

```
data: {
  newInputs: {}
}
```

проходите по вашему массиву и создаете разметку с реактивными обработчиками и прилагающими:

```
   <div v-for="item in inputs">
      <label for="name">{{ item['v-model'] }}</label>
      <input v-model="newInputs[item['v-model']]" type="text" id="name" required>
    </div>
```

Пример для наглядности:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    newInputs: {},
    inputs: [{
        type: 'text',
        'v-model': 'name',
      },
      {
        type: 'text',
        'v-model': 'age'
      },
      {
        type: 'text',
        'v-model': 'gender',
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in inputs">
      <label for="name">{{ item['v-model'] }}</label>
      <input v-model="newInputs[item['v-model']]" type="text" id="name" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ newInputs }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если изначально v-model:="gender" имеет значение, то в этом случае оно не выводит старое значение.
К примеру перебор массива data , в него уже записывается значение v-model:="data.gender"

Comment: если честно, не совсем понимаю о чем речь, но если вы изначально установите  `newInputs: {}` в `newInputs: { gender: 'male' }`, то оно будет выведено при первой отрисовке и будет реактивно